# Invalidating individual keys from rack-cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rack, rack-cache

Let's say a path on my rails app got stuck in rack cache. Is there a way to say: "/games/zelda" should be removed/invalidated from rack-cache?

Comment: What [storage](https://rtomayko.github.io/rack-cache/storage) do you use?

Comment: @spickermann I use Dalli/memcached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assumtions**

1. Your rails app is named `MyApp`
2. the complete url you wish to purge is http://www.myapp.com/games/zelda

**Step 1** obtain a normalized key

```
mock_request = Rack::MockRequest.env_for('/games/zelda', {"SERVER_NAME"=>"www.myapp.com"})
key = Rack::Cache::Key.call(Rack::Cache::Request.new(mock_request))
```

**Step 2** retrieve storage objects

```
metastore_uri = MyApp::Application.config.action_dispatch.rack_cache[:metastore]
entitystore_uri = MyApp::Application.config.action_dispatch.rack_cache[:entitystore]

metastore = Rack::Cache::Storage.instance.resolve_metastore_uri(metastore_uri)
entitystore = Rack::Cache::Storage.instance.resolve_entitystore_uri(entitystore_uri)
```

**Step 3** retrieve the metadata

```
stored_meta = metastore.read(key)
```

**Step 4** purge the entity store for each compression type

```
stored_meta.each do |sm|
  entitystore.purge(sm[1]["X-Content-Digest"])
end
```

**Step 5** purge the metastore

```
metastore.purge(key)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete one key or all keys from an Memcached instance. Unfortunately doesn't allow to list all keys. Therefore you cannot iterate over all keys and just delete the one you want to invalidate.

That said I see two options:

1. Delete all keys in Memcached.
2. Or change the path in the URI of your [Memcached Storage](https://rtomayko.github.io/rack-cache/storage) config and re-cache all keys.